# Flink file read heap memory exception

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am  reading a file in flink as:

```
   val avroInputFormat =
          new AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord](new org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path(url), classOf[GenericRecord])
        env.createInput(avroInputFormat).collect().asScala.toList
```

And i am running into the exception:

Exception java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Internal server error.,

Increasing the heap size is not a good idea. How to change this code to avoid the exception.

Please help me in optimizing the code.

Comment: How do You know it's OOM exception ??

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Internal server error., <Exception on server side:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: And what are You trying to achieve there with the file ??

Comment: I want to multiple large files with avro data and tranform them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the error You are making there is invoking the `collect` method, which will get all elements from the given file on the machine to create a `List`. So, You generally have two options:

1) Remove the `collect` as this is most probably not needed for Your us ecase, which is to transform files and output them (as per comments)

2) If You really, really need to have this `collect` for some specific reason, you should increase the heap to allow collecting of the files you want to process.

Comment: What could be the other option besides the collect, as i want to take the data from file and extract some of the fields and  transform them.Can i do it in splits somehow?

Comment: Why don't you simply process this as Dataset, using Dataset api ??